# Question closed as "exact duplicate" but is not an exact duplicate

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28836/6757) was closed as being an "exact duplicate" of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28519/6757).

However:

- The question that was closed is a *specific* question: what is the solution to the specific problem of finding threads (containing emails) labeled "To-do" which are currently shown in the inbox. The solution to this might involve searching by emails rather than by threads; but we don't know yet since the problem hasn't been solved.
- By contrast, the question that was left open is a *general* question (which happened to use the same example): is it possible to search by thread in Gmail?

Clearly, these are not exact duplicates. Please can the question which was closed be reopened?

Answer (score 2):

I answered your original question which shows that there is a misunderstanding on how tags work (threads cannot be tagged only the messages within via manual process or filters), thus invalidating your second question.

The question remains as a duplicate subset question of your original question.

Comment: The second question is still very much a valid one!

Comment: @sampablokuper `This question covers exactly the same content as earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with another identical question.`

Answer (score 1):

In both questions you even refer to the bug you submitted to Google. Here is a suggestion: Take the first question and offer a bounty.

Several people have tried to duplicate the error you are seeing. Unfortunately we have struck out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "struck out", but I'd be grateful to know :) Particularly, in step 5 of the "steps to reproduce", did you find that the thread *was* in the search results, or did you find that it *wasn't*? As for bounties, the last time I've offered one on a StackExchange site, it wasn't very productive :(

Comment: No matter what I try label, in, quotes, no quotes, dash, no dash, It always return the results I expect.

Comment: Which results do you expect? I.e. do they match the description under "Steps to reproduce" or the different description under "Expected behaviour", or are they different to both of those (and if so, what are they)?

Comment: When I search by hand I find X results, when I use the search tool I get X results. I can't reproduce the bug.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the distinction you're making between searching "by hand" or with "the search tool". The steps refer to entering a particular query in the search box which is visible at the top of the Gmail interface. Also, what do you mean by "X results"? Does the thread which you've *only* tagged "To-do" after sending, and to which your correspondent has then replied, appear in the search results for `in:inbox label:To-do` or not? (Also, just to check we're on the same page check: you do have "conversations" enabled in the Gmail settings, yes?) Thanks.

Comment: Searching by hand is when you don't use the automated tools to find all the messages, that is ground truth. So far you are the only one with this bug. I can't propose solutions if I can't recreate the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're using terminology I don't understand in this context. Which "automated tools" do you mean? (E.g. do you consider the Gmail search box an "automated tool" or not?) Also, what is "ground truth"?